# PhpThumb и url?

Tags: phpthumb, php

```
<img class='img_mini' src='protected/extensions/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=<путь к изображению>&w=207&h=300'>
```

может ли <путь к изображению> быть ссылкой на изображение в интернете и как реализовать чтобы отображалось правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работал с таким плагином, но наверняка это нельзя, т.к. в переменной src в строке будет прямой слэш, который будет означать что это дирректория вашего сервера и произойдет 404 ошибка.

Другое дело что можно попробовать сделать таблицу соответствий в БД, например писать md5 хэш пути к изображению и реальный путь, в src соответственно у вас будет подставляться хэш. За тем получаем по хэшу реальный путь и отдаем его на съедение phpThumb'у.